# Write to file descriptor 3 without writing to disk?

Tags: bash, shell, file-descriptor

Is there a way to interact with file descriptors without having to open a file on disk?

This won't work without a file first being assigned to fd3:

```
echo a >&3
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use `mkfifo` to create a [fifo queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), that will create an entry in the filesystem but the actual io through it will be in memory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do. Suppose you want to write strings at your leisure and print them reversed. set up a file descriptor redirecting into a process substitution waiting for stdin:

```
$ exec 3> >(rev)
$ echo hello world >&3
dlrow olleh
```

When you're done with it, you can close the file descriptor

```
$ exec 3>&-
$ echo hello world >&3
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: My understanding is that this *is* on-disk in some platforms (where `/dev/fd` isn't available, and thus a named pipe gets used instead).